# What does the dashed line between diodes in a CMOS protection network mean?

Tags: diodes, cmos

On the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4007ub.pdf) for CD4007 there are schematics for the input protection network:

[image: CD4007 input protection network]

and the output protection network:

[image: CD4007 output protection network]

On both, there are 2 diodes connected by a dashed line (D2 on the input and D1 on the output).

What does the dashed line mean?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The dashed line means that the diode is actually distributed across the resistor structure. The resistor is made using a doped region in the silicon, and there is an inherent PN junction between this doped region and the underlying silicon that contains it. So there is really just one diode, not two, but it is neither before nor after the resistor...it is part of the physical resistor structure itself.

Comment: Does it have any special properties compared to putting the resistor and the diode in series, or is the schematic just being specific as to the implementation of that resistor/diode structure?

Comment: I don't know much about the properties of these distributed diodes, but if the diode and resistor were separate devices, and the diode was after the resistor, then it would be more straightforward to see how the resistor would limit the current through the diode.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know the official name of such a structure? I cannot find much about it with any permutation of _diode_, _resistor_ and _distributed_.

Comment: Schrödinger's diode :-)

Comment: @AlexMalcoci Try searching for "diffused resistor". The resistors were originally created by diffusing dopants into the silicon. These days they would be created via ion implantation, so I suppose you could also try "implanted resistor".

Comment: @RussellMcMahon it turns into transistor when you decap the chip

Comment: @Maple: got any photos or links or other sources? :)

Comment: @AlexMalcoci It's just a very simple structure that happens to get the job done. Separate diodes and resistor would be more complicated.